# Android: Problem in DataBase

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I created a data base which had an information about some places ..then I retrieve from DB to show the places on a Google map..

when I debug the application this exception occurs "SQLiteCursor.finalize()" in IllegalStateException Class..

and this is a logcat output :

```
04-18 14:58:51.815: ERROR/ActivityThread(263): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
04-18 14:58:51.825: ERROR/ActivityThread(263): Failed to find provider info for       com.google.settings
04-18 14:58:51.975: ERROR/ActivityThread(263): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
04-18 14:58:52.845: DEBUG/dalvikvm(263): GC freed 3178 objects / 193168 bytes in 80ms
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263): Leak found
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263): java.lang.IllegalStateException: /data/data/ksu.project.gotour/databases/GoTour.db SQLiteDatabase created and never closed
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase. <init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1694)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:738)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:760)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:753)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.app.ApplicationContext.openOrCreateDatabase(ApplicationContext.java:473)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:193)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at   ksu.project.gotour.EventData.Visited(EventData.java:236)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at ksu.project.gotour.spotInfo$2.onCheckedChanged(spotInfo.java:73)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:122)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:85)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:97)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6540)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-18 14:58:53.445: ERROR/Database(263):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 14:58:53.805: DEBUG/dalvikvm(263): GC freed 844 objects / 73448 bytes in 135ms
04-18 14:58:54.176: ERROR/Exception on query(263): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
04-18 14:58:57.075: DEBUG/dalvikvm(263): threadid=5: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1 s=Y)
04-18 14:58:57.075: DEBUG/dalvikvm(263): GC freed 5454 objects / 334000 bytes in 92ms
04-18 14:59:00.556: INFO/MapActivity(263): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
04-18 14:59:03.896: INFO/dalvikvm(263): Debugger is attached -- suppressing HeapWorker watchdog
```

And this is a picture for logcat. Maybe it is more clear.

http://download.mrkzy.com/e/1811_md_13031326851.png
http://download.mrkzy.com/e/1811_md_13031326852.png

Thanks a lot

Comment: the message is pretty clear: you're not closing the database before you stop using it. fix that.

Comment: based on log here i think you didnt close the database object you created in your class. you have use dbObj.close();

Comment: Could you please post your code from ksu.project.gotour.EventData.Visited(EventData.java:236) ? You should check whenever you are using database helper right: you don't need to open database before every query. You need to do it only once in Activity lifecycle. Also, don't forget to close the database in onPause callback.

Answer (score 0):

The exception `"SQLiteCursor.finalize()" in IllegalStateException Class` can appear if you are not closing cursors when they are not needed anymore. So, do not forget to execute `close()` for cursors. 
It's not critical exception, so the app can live with that, but when debugging eclipse breaks on this exception.

Comment: I'm closing the cursor and DB in each activity..
no there are some activities not working because of this exception:(